# Como llamar a varios firechos JSON a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

tengo un inconveniente para importar varios archivos JSON a Javascript.

**JSON 1**

```
[
 {
  "id": 217123,
  "nombre": "Jorge",
  "apellido": "Benavides",
  "edad": 42
 }
]
```

**JSON 2**

```
[
 {
  "id": 23411,
  "nombre": "Antonio",
  "apellido": "Perez",
  "edad": 56
 }
]
```

y mas archivos JSON...

En Javascrip he hecho esto pero me da error el `require`

```
const jsonData = require('./archivo1.json'); 
console.log(jsonData);
```

También he hecho esto pero me da error.

```
import { jsonData } from './archivo2.json';
console.log(jsonData);
```

Deseo presentar estos datos JSON a Javascrit y unirlos en uno solo al ser llamados de otros ficheros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se trata de un `JSON` no puedes importarlos simplemente con un `require` y tampoco con un `import`, y voy a asumir que estas usando `nodeJS` para cargar los `JSON`, porque de lo contrario definitivamente el `require` te va a saltar un error.

Yo por ejemplo, la forma mas fácil en la que cargaria los `JSON` es usando un `fetch`:

```
const jsons = [];

async function loadJSONS(){
   jsons.push(await fetch("url_hacia_tus_json/json1.json").then(res => res.json()));
   jsons.push(await fetch("url_hacia_tus_json/json2.json").then(res => res.json()));
   console.log(jsons);
}

loadJSONS();
```

Ahora bien, si vas a unir los `json`, porque no simplemente pones la información del `JSON` en un solo archivo?, hacer un `join` de `JSONS` no es tan facil como hacer un join de `arrays`.

Si te preguntas que es el `await` y porque le pongo `async` a la `function`:

- `async` hace que javascript tome el comportamiento de la función como asincrono, ademas, hace que independientemente de si haces uso de la sentencia `return` o no, la funcion con solo ser asincrona ya te retornara una `promise`.
- `await` es una palabra clave que solo puede ser usada en contextos asincronos, por ello es necesario que la funcion sea descrita como asincrona, `await` pausa la ejecucion del codigo y la resume cuando la promesa haya sido resuelta o rechazada, devolviendonos asi ya sea un valor o un error.

Ten en cuenta que si no usas el `async` y el `await` al ser la carga de archivos una operacion asincrona, es muy probable que ocurran cosas extrañas a tus ojos, como por ejemplo que en un inicio el `array` se encuentre vació, pero que tiempo despues y por arte de magia en otra parte del codigo ya posea informacion, justo por eso es el `await`, para que el flujo se pause y esperar a que todo se cargue.

Comment: O la otra opcion es que si quieres usar una sentencia `import` para cargar los archivos es que en vez de usar un `.json` uses un `.js` y exportes una variable que contenga el `json` y luego lo importes en el archivo que lo necesitas.

Comment: Mas o menos estaba pensando en algo así, de llamar las variables e importarlos para ser llamados.

Comment: El detalle de que porque no utilizo un solo JSON es que estoy manejando mas de 700 mil registros y solo un archivo me pesa mas de 400 MB y el hosting no me permite subir semejante tamaño, así que lo segmenté por pedazos, en esta caso por provincias y así llamarlos a cada uno al "main" Javascript. No estoy usando NODEJS.

Comment: En ese caso al no usar `nodeJS` no debes usar `require` ya que es un metodo que solo existe en `nodeJS`, sobre lo de los registros... probablemente edite mi respuesta para ver que se podria hacer, apenas pueda edito mi respuesta.